# How to find what servlet will serve given resource?

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

If I want to redirect a request to some other resource, I can do sth. like:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher (resource).forward (request, response);
```

But is there a way to find out what servlet will be used to serve that `resource` in advance? I ask because it seems I need to set content-type on the response before redirecting in my setup, since otherwise (if target servlet tries to set it) it gets ignored. So, I'd like to know what I'm redirecting to to determine the proper content-type in advance.

**EDIT:**

In other words what I have:

```
SERVLET_1  ==> [resource] SERVLET_2
```

For some reason, when `SERVLET_2` sets content-type it gets ignored. Therefore, I need to set it in `SERVLET_1`, but for response content that `SERVLET_2` will generate. So, to make a proper decision `SERVLET_1` needs to know what `SERVLET_2` is going to be. Can it somehow find it from the `resource`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the myme type of file by [getMimetype()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMimeType%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(resourcePath);
```

> Returns the MIME type of the specified file, or null if the MIME type is not known. The MIME type is determined by the configuration of the servlet container, and may be specified in a web application deployment descriptor. Common MIME types include text/html and image/gif.

Comment: It's not a file. It's a servlet that can *generate* something on-the-fly. I don't know if it will be JSON or HTML, for example.

Comment: @user2667759 Then the logic should be there where it's generation.